# He hasn't send me any pictures or he didn't send me any pictures

Tags: grammar, learning

> He hasn't send me any pictures

or

> He didn't send me any pictures

Which is correct?

Comment: It could be either (but note that the first should be "He **hasn't sent**"). The first is ***present perfect tense*** and the second is ***simple past***. Both are fine, but have a different meaning and are used in different contexts. Can you tell us what specifically is confusing you about these choices, and what research you have already done? Otherwise, unfortunately general proof-reading questions are off-topic here, and so are questions that can be answered with standard references. You also might be interested in our sister site, [English Language Learners].

Answer (score 2):

"He didn't send me any pictures" is **past tense** and refers to a specific time period:  perhaps you were waiting for some pictures last week, for example.  Consider this sentence:

*"I was waiting right up until the publishing deadline, but **he didn't send me any pictures**.  He sent them the next day, but it was too late then - we'd missed the deadline.*"

"He hasn't sent me any pictures" (note "hasn't sent", not "haven't send") is present tense: because it describes the situation now, it means that he has not **ever** sent you any pictures.  eg

*"It's only ten minutes to the publishing deadline and he still hasn't sent me any pictures."*

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you say " he has not sent any pictures" it kind of imply he has not yet but he "did not" implies he simply did not.